# How to POST Array to Web Service with AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Google Chrome Extension. I have string array and I need post my array to web service with ajax and return again. Here is my code:

```
 var data = {};
data.param1 = words; // my string array

$.ajax({
    data: JSON.stringify( data ),
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'http://localhost:49242/Service.asmx',
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) {
        alert("basarili");
    },
    failure: function(errMsg) {
    alert(errMsg);
}
});
```

Service:

```
public string example(string[] param1) {

        string result = param1[0];
        return result;
    }
```

I am not getting an error but this code is not working. How can I solve?

Comment: do you have debug your code step by step ? do you have see what you send, what you get ?

Comment: you mean `param1[""param1"]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = {};
data.param1 = words; // my string array

$.ajax({
    data: {param1: data.param1},
    url: 'http://localhost:49242/Service.asmx',
    type: "POST",
    success: function (result) {
        alert("basarili");
    },
    failure: function(errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Json Encode** while returning string in the Service file.

Comment: can you write an example?

Comment: For example, in your Service file you can convert string to JSON format and then return it.

     public string example(string[] param1) {
          string result = param1[0];   
          var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
          return serializer.Serialize(new { Name = result });        
     }

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I have given similar answer in

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36584311/jquery-ajax-call-to-asp-net-webservice-fails/36588094#36588094)

As per my observation

```
var data = {};
data.param1 = ["String1","String2"]; // my string array

$.ajax({
    data: JSON.stringify( data ),
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'http://localhost:49242/Service.asmx/example',//Missing Method Name 
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.d);
    },
    failure: function(errMsg) {
    alert(errMsg);
}
});
```

and .aspx

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    //rest is omitted 
    <asp:scriptmanager ID="Scriptmanager1" runat="server">
        <Services>
            <asp:ServiceReference runat="server" Path="~/WebService1.asmx"/>

        </Services>

    </asp:scriptmanager>
    </form>
```

and

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]//This is must
public string example(string[] param1) {

        string result = param1[0];
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I don't have a web form (.aspx) . Is it a problem?

Comment: I tested in jQuery .It will work with out **scriptmanager**.The problem is in your method .check the ajax call .

Comment: Did ur web service works perfectly? What does ur result show? Paste ur word object?

Comment: Service is working perfectly. When I writed a string manually in url, return a value correctly. But I can't send a variable to service. I think the problem is here:                                                                            $.ajax({
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "Service.asmx/kok_bul",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
    }
    });

Comment: `alert(result)` will not show anytingin asp.net . try `alert(result.d)`